# MiKTeX gives error upon attempting to typeset

Tags: miktex

I am a Mac user of LaTeX who is forced to use Windows at work, so I'm clueless when things go wrong.

I've been using MiKTeX quite successfully until yesterday, when I all of a sudden had 2 MiKTeX icons in the tray at the bottom of the page, and started getting the below message when I try to typeset a document:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9)
log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (pdflatex).
log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly.

Sorry, but "C:\Users\ReedAR\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.EXE" did not succeed.

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (texify).
log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly.

Sorry, but "C:\Users\ReedAR\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\texify.exe" did not succeed.

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
```

I found nothing to help on the MiKTeX project page (I may not know where to look) and have tried reinstalling the program to no avail.

Suggestions?

Comment: I would say your system is not up-to-date. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108490/2388. But I would suggest to install texlive, then you have the same texsystem on both OS.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer suggesting to install texlive might not help in his case, since the QO is using a corporate machine. He probably lacks the necessary rights. And the corporate may have issues to switch

Comment: @Naphaneal: If the OP has the rights to install miktex he/she can also install texlive. I did install both on accounts with restricted rights without problems -- actually texlive should be easier as it doesn't write in the registry (and there is an option to create a portable system).

Comment: On Windows, as on unix systems, programs don't change just like that ;) Is a log file written? If you say you have two tray symbols, is it possible, that a second installation of miktex was performed along the old one? This may cause errors in the registry...

Comment: Try this: close all programs, and then open a command prompt and type texify junk.  (Where junk is any random string you like)  See if that helps.